# How to format text to ######.##

Tags: c#, .net

how to limit text to 6 numbers . 2 numbers ?

(######.##)

thank's in advance

Comment: Do you mean restricting user input to that format. is this winforms or ASP.net

Comment: Is this about a user control's input mask or something?

Comment: "without any rounding"? If the value is 0.005, what would you have it display?

Comment: 000000.00 I guess. Even though truncation is a form of rounding.

Comment: If you are formatting output, what would you display if the number is 1,000,000?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use either the `String.Format` method or the `ToString` method:

```
double value = 123.456;
string formatted1 = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:######.##}", value);
string formatted2 = value.ToString("######.##", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you use `#` in the formatting string, those will be filled with spaces if there are no significant digits there. For example `123.456` formatted using `"######.##"` will be `"  123.46"`.

If you use `0` in the formatting string, those will be filled with zeroes of there are no significant digits there. For example `123.456` formatted using `"000000.00"` will be `"000123.46"`.

You can combine `#` and `0` to get different results. For example you might want spaces before the decimal separator, but always at least one digit: `"#####0.00"`.

The period character is used to specify the decimal separator. This is a period for some culture settings and a comma for other. You always use the period in the format string, but the output depends on the culture settings. If you always want a period in the output you can use the `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` culture.

If you don't want the number to be rounded, you have to truncate it before formatting it:

```
double value = 123.456;
value = Math.Truncate(value * 100.0) / 100.0;
```

Answer (score 8):

```
 // without leading zeros
string formatted = String.Format("{0:######.##}", value);

// with leading zeros
string formatted = String.Format("{0:000000.00}", value);
```